# I can't upgrade from 9.5.11 to 10.2.0

Tags: composer

I'm not able to upgrade my website from Drupal 9.5.11 to 10.2.0 via Composer. I don't think there is something wrong with the module versions; the *Upgrade status* module gives me a *good to go*. The problem is that I don't get any detail on the error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
  - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.2.0].
  - drupal/core-recommended 10.2.0 requires drupal/core 10.2.0 -> found drupal/core[10.2.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

This is the content of the composer.json file.

```json
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        },
        {
          "type": "package",
          "package": {
            "name": "bower-asset/photoswipe",
            "version": "4.1.1",
            "type": "drupal-library",
            "dist": {
              "url": "https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/archive/v4.1.1.zip",
              "type": "zip"
            }
          }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "cure53/dompurify",
                "version": "3.0.3",
                "type": "drupal-library",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "3.0.3"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "arthurkushman/query-path": "^3.0",
        "bower-asset/lazysizes": "^5.1",
        "bower-asset/photoswipe": "^5",
        "campaignmonitor/createsend-php": "^6.1",
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "cure53/dompurify": "^3.0",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal/account_field_split": "^2.0.2",
        "drupal/address": "^1",
        "drupal/addtoany": "^2.0",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.4",
        "drupal/advagg": "^6.0@alpha",
        "drupal/antibot": "^1.3",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0.3",
        "drupal/blazy": "^2.22",
        "drupal/block_class": "^1.0",
        "drupal/block_field": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/cer": "^5.0@beta",
        "drupal/ckeditor_config": "^3.2",
        "drupal/clientside_validation": "^4.0",
        "drupal/composer_deploy": "^1.7",
        "drupal/condition_query": "^1.4",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^4.0@alpha",
        "drupal/config_ignore": "^2.1",
        "drupal/config_views": "^2.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "9.5.11",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "9.5.11",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "9.5.11",
        "drupal/ctools": "^4.0",
        "drupal/ctools_views": "dev-4.x",
        "drupal/devel": "5.x-dev",
        "drupal/draggableviews": "^2.0",
        "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^2.0",
        "drupal/email_registration": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.2",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.10",
        "drupal/extlink": "^1.1",
        "drupal/feeds": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/feeds_ex": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/feeds_log": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/feeds_tamper": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/fences": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/field_group": "~3.0",
        "drupal/fivestar": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/flag": "^4.0@alpha",
        "drupal/flood_control": "^2.2",
        "drupal/formblock": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/geofield": "^1.8",
        "drupal/geofield_map": "^3.0",
        "drupal/google_tag": "^1.4",
        "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
        "drupal/image_delta_formatter": "^1.0",
        "drupal/image_effects": "^3.0",
        "drupal/imageapi_optimize": "^4.0@beta",
        "drupal/imageapi_optimize_binaries": "^1.0",
        "drupal/imageapi_optimize_tinypng": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/imageapi_optimize_webp": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/imagefield_tokens": "^3.1",
        "drupal/imagemagick": "^3.4",
        "drupal/imce": "^3.0",
        "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_autocomplete": "^2.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker": "^2.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_menu": "^2.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_slider": "^2.0",
        "drupal/lazy": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/libraries": "^4.0",
        "drupal/link_attributes": "^2.1",
        "drupal/login_destination": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/menu_item_extras": "^2.11",
        "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.3",
        "drupal/menu_trail_by_path": "^2.0",
        "drupal/mgv": "^2.2",
        "drupal/mobile_detect": "^3.0",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^4.0",
        "drupal/module_missing_message_fixer": "^2.0",
        "drupal/node_class": "2.0.x-dev",
        "drupal/office_hours": "^1.2",
        "drupal/path_redirect_import": "^2.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.11",
        "drupal/pathologic": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/photoswipe": "^5.0@alpha",
        "drupal/physical": "^1.3",
        "drupal/poll": "^1.4",
        "drupal/profile": "^1.7",
        "drupal/queue_ui": "^3.1",
        "drupal/quick_node_clone": "^1.11",
        "drupal/r4032login": "2.2.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.8",
        "drupal/responsive_favicons": "^1.4",
        "drupal/rules": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^1.1",
        "drupal/schema_metatag": "3.0.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.29",
        "drupal/search_api_autocomplete": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/search_api_location": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/search_autocomplete": "^3.0",
        "drupal/semanticviews": "^2.2",
        "drupal/sophron": "^1.3",
        "drupal/state_machine": "^1.10",
        "drupal/structure_sync": "^2.0",
        "drupal/svg_image": "^1.15",
        "drupal/symfony_mailer": "^1.1@beta",
        "drupal/tablefield": "^2.1",
        "drupal/taxonomy_manager": "2.0.9",
        "drupal/taxonomy_menu": "^3.4",
        "drupal/telephone_validation": "^2.2",
        "drupal/token": "^1.3",
        "drupal/token_filter": "^2.1",
        "drupal/tvi": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^3.2",
        "drupal/unpublished_nodes_redirect": "^2.0",
        "drupal/unused_modules": "^1.0",
        "drupal/upgrade_status": "^4.0",
        "drupal/user_registrationpassword": "2.0.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "2.x-dev",
        "drupal/viewfield": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/views_block_area": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/views_block_filter_block": "^2.0",
        "drupal/views_conditional": "^1.5",
        "drupal/views_extras": "^3.0",
        "drupal/views_random_seed": "^1.2",
        "drupal/votingapi": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/webform": "6.2.2",
        "drupal/webform_node_element": "^1.2",
        "drupal/xmlsitemap": "^1.4",
        "drupal/yaml_editor": "^1.0",
        "drupal/yoast_seo": "^1.7",
        "drush/drush": "^11",
        "kint-php/kint": "dev-master",
        "npm-asset/photoswipe-dynamic-caption-plugin": "^1",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "^2.0",
        "php-http/httplug": "^2.2",
        "psr/http-factory": "1.0.x-dev",
        "roave/better-reflection": "6.14.x-dev",
        "softcreatr/jsonpath": "^0.7.5",
        "symfony/error-handler": "^4|^5|^6",
        "symfony/filesystem": "^4|^5|^6",
        "symfony/http-client-contracts": "^2.5.2",
        "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "^2.2",
        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "v2.x-dev",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6 || ^7.5",
        "psr/container": "^1"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": false,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform-check": false,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true,
            "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": true
        }
    },
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "www/modules/contrib/webform/composer.libraries.json"
        ]
    },

    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "www/"
            },
            "file-mapping": {
              "[web-root]/sites/development.services.yml": false
            }
        },
        "patches": {

        },

        "installer-types": ["bower-asset", "npm-asset"],

        "installer-paths": {
            "www/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "www/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset"
            ],
            "www/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "www/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "www/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "www/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "www/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "www/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have a hint on where to start?

Comment: Are you following Drupal’s upgrade documentation?

Comment: Your composer.json declares 9.x versions for Drupal. How are you attempting to upgrade?

Comment: Remove Drush. It will require Drush 12, and you will need to add it back when you have completed the upgrade to 10.2. When you remove it, then do `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^10` along with core-composer-scaffold and core-project-message.

Comment: @Clive I'm trying to update via the command `composer require drupal/core-recommended:10.2.0 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.2.0 drupal/core-project-message:10.2.0 --update-with-all-dependencies`

Comment: As mentioned above Drush has been an impediment to some upgrades. But overall I recommend Drupal’s official major version upgrade documentation as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

First confirm that you have php8.1

```
php -v
```

Then I recommend that you check each of the modules that you have installed in Drupal, and confirm that it is in the require section in the composer.json file.

my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.2",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.24",
    "drupal/ckeditor5": "^1.0@dev",
    "drupal/ckeditor_font": "^1.3",
    "drupal/ckeditor_loremipsum": "^2.2",
    "drupal/ckeditor_media_embed": "^1.11",
    "drupal/ckeditor_spoiler": "^2.0",
    "drupal/ckeditor_videodetector": "^2.1",
    "drupal/ckwordcount": "^2.1",
    "drupal/codesnippet": "^1.9",
    "drupal/color": "^1.0",
    "drupal/colorbutton": "^1.3",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.0",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.0",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.0",
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^9.0",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.9",
    "drupal/devel_php": "^1.3",
    "drupal/domain_registration": "^1.6",
    "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^2.0",
    "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^2.1",
    "drupal/examples": "^3.0",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.3",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^4.0",
    "drupal/hal": "^1.0",
    "drupal/honeypot": "^2.0",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_slider": "^1.1",
    "drupal/metatag": "^1.16",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.10",
    "drupal/quickedit": "^1.0",
    "drupal/rdf": "^2.0",
    "drupal/recaptcha_v3": "^1.8",
    "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.4",
    "drupal/xmlsitemap": "^1.2",
    "drush/drush": "^10.6"
},
```

If, for example, you have the drush module installed, but you do not see it in your composer file, I recommend that you install the module through composer:

```
composer require drush/drush
```

After you have all the modules installed in the composer.json file, proceed to install the following module:

```
composer require drupal/upgrade_status
```

This module will help you with the update process.

Comment: Hi Jhonatan! Upgrade Status is installed and it's fully compatible. The problem has something to do with drush. If I require it with composer:

 `Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drush/drush 12.x-dev -> satisfiable by drush/drush[12.x-dev].
    - drush/drush 12.x-dev requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.0-beta.1, ..., 7.9.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 6.5.x-dev (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as ...`

But I can't upgrade to Guzzle 7, cause then it complains D9.5.11 needs it!